# Add style sheet for a specific browser language

Tags: asp.net, css

I am trying to obtain a particular style for a input considering the browser language.

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="name" onchange="setNameValue" class="name" />
```

and the css file looks like:

```
.name
{
   width: 120px;
}
```

i would like this line to be considered for a es-MX(spanish) language, but to not affecting other regions. something like...but is not working

```
 .name:lang("es-MX")
    {
      width: 120px;
      margin-right:6px;
    }
```

Can someone advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked added different style class considering user browser language for me with:

```
name:lang(de)
{
  width: 120px;
  margin-right:6px;
}

name:lang(en)
{
  width: 120px;
  margin-right:16px;
}
```

and `<input type="text" runat="server" id="name" onchange="setNameValue" class="name" lang="es"/>`

Answer (score 1):

What about setting the lang attribute to the element you want to target:

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="name" onchange="setNameValue" class="name" lang="es" />
```

You can find more about the lang property at the bottom of this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms

Comment: And were the style is maintained? The lang "es" is not determing the language of the input?

Comment: well as I understand it, users with spanish dictionary installed in will have spanish input

Comment: The attribute doesn't have an impact on the style of the input box